# Combining two Postgresql similar tables located on two different machines

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have two Windows machines (PC1 & PC2) with PostgreSQL in both. In PC1 I have the table:

[image]

And in PC2 I have the same table with the following records:

[image]

I want to combine both tables and put them in PC1 to be like (the order is not important):

[image]

How can do that? I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 & pgAdminIII. I prefer,if possible, to transfer the data using USB stick rather than a network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i would have done:

PC1-> pgadmin-> yourtablename -> right click -> backup

File options: format:plain, encoding:your_ecnoding

dump options #1: only data, use column inserts.

this will create the sql query. **replace yourtablename with yourtablename2** and excecute it on PC2

*delete duplicate records and add data:*

```
delete from yourtablename2 where id in (select id from yourtablename)

insert into yourtablename 
select * from yourtablename2

drop table yourtablename2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just dump your data out:

```
pg_dump --data-only dbname > outfile.sql
```

This will give you a file of all the data. The big issue if you'll have to worry about duplicates when inserting this data back into the other node.

This is how you'd import the data:

```
psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on dbname < outfile.sql
```

Another solution for you if you continue to need these two databases synced is to use some of PostgreSQL's replication strategies. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION